# How to change permissions of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf of Ec2 while copying httpd.conf from .ebextensions?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, permissions, ebextensions

I have .ebextensions directory in the top of the war file. 
.ebextensions has 01movehttpd.config and httpd directory. Insider httpd is httpd.conf.

In the config file, I have

```
#files:
# yada yada yada
container_commands:
 00_rewrite:
  command: cp -f .ebextensions/httpd/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/
  ignoreErrors: true
```

But whenever I deploy war file to beanstalk I don't see new httpd.conf being moved to /etc/httpd/conf/

When I checked by ssh ing to Ec2, I found out

```
cp: cannot remove ‘/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf’: Permission denied
```

How can I grant permissions, so that in future when I create new environment and deploy war files, I don't experience same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo!

command: sudo cp -f .ebextensions/httpd/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/